# How would I get these two drop down menus right next to each other?

Tags: html, web

On my website [Website](http://moviemagic.ucoz.com/publ/) I can't seem to get these drop down menus right next to each other, how would I do that?

This is the code I have...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>$MODULE_NAME$ - $SITE_NAME$</title>
<?$META_DESCRIPTION$?>

<link type="text/css" rel="StyleSheet" href="/_st/my.css" />
</head>
<body>
$ADMIN_BAR$
$GLOBAL_AHEADER$
<!-- <middle> -->
<div id="maincol">
$MODULE_SEARCH_FORM$
<!-- <body> --><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="80%"><a href="$HOME_PAGE_LINK$"><!--<s5176>-->MAIN<!--</s>--></a> &raquo;     <!--<s5208>-->MOVIES<!--</s>--></td>
<td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap;"><?if($ADD_ENTRY_LINK$)?>[ <a href="$ADD_ENTRY_LINK$"><!--<s5202>-->Add new entry<!--</s>--></a> ]<?endif?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr />
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<div>
<form name="yearselect">FILTER BY:
<select name="menu" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
<option selected="selected">YEAR</option>
<option value="year/1">2014</option>
<option value="year/2">2013</option>
</select>
</form>
</div><div>
<form name="genreselect">
<select name="menu" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
<option selected="selected">GENRE</option>
<option value="URL">Action</option>
<option value="URL">Horror</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
<td align="right"><?if($PAGE_SELECTOR$)?><!--<s3015>-->Pages<!--</s>-->:         $PAGE_SELECTOR$<?endif?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr />
$BODY$
<?if($PAGE_SELECTOR1$)?><div style="text-align:center;">$PAGE_SELECTOR1$</div><?endif?>        <!-- </body> -->
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
<div id="soc">
<?if($RSS_LINK$)?><a href="$RSS_LINK$" target="_blank" title="RSS" class="soc-rss"></a>        <?endif?>
<a href="http://del.icio.us/post?url=$HOME_PAGE_LINK$" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Del.icio.us" class="soc-del"></a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=$HOME_PAGE_LINK$" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="FaceBook" class="soc-facebook"></a>
<a href="http://memori.ru/link/?sm=1&u_data[url]=$HOME_PAGE_LINK$" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Memori" class="soc-memori"></a>
<a href="http://vkontakte.ru/share.php?url=$HOME_PAGE_LINK$" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Vkontakte" class="soc-vkontakte"></a>
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=$HOME_PAGE_LINK$" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Twitter" class="soc-twitter"></a>
</div>
$GLOBAL_CLEFTER$
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<!-- </middle> -->
</div>
</div>
$GLOBAL_BFOOTER$
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That is the full source of the code but, I only need help with  part..

Comment: What drop down menus right next to each other mean,please post your full src. I check if no css it ok

Comment: I have posted full source, @tuanhuynh

Answer (score 1):

Here's a valid HTML5 solution to your problem, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/3V6Ht/)

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>FILTER BY:
        <select name="yearselect">
          <option selected="selected">YEAR</option>
          <option value="year/1">2014</option>
          <option value="year/2">2013</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td> 
        <select name="genreselect">
          <option selected="selected">GENRE</option>
          <option value="URL">Action</option>
          <option value="URL">Horror</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: When I try this the drop down menus don't work @mdesdev

Answer (score 0):

Avoid table!! Refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbbottam/qb9vA/)

Markup:

```
<div>
    <form name="yearselect">FILTER BY:
        <select name="menu" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
            <option selected="selected">YEAR</option>
            <option value="year/1">2014</option>
            <option value="year/2">2013</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div><div>
    <form name="genreselect">
        <select name="menu" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
            <option selected="selected">GENRE</option>
            <option value="URL">Action</option>
            <option value="URL">Horror</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have the table stretching all the way across the div, and each drop down centered in each column. You need to set a max width on the table's div so that it will only spread a certain width and then the drop downs will not spread further apart from that. Or, you could put them in the same column (so basically no table) and justify them to one side.